# Append returning nonetupe

Tags: python, append, typeerror, nonetype

I am running a script to send Spotify album ids (20 at a time) to the Spotify API and save track counts from each album id to a list, which I then insert into the existing data frame before saving to a .csv file.

The file is rather large (1 million + lines) and for approx 900,000 of them, I encountered no issue. However, I eventually came across a TypeError: "NoneType" object is not subscriptable

The common issue seems to be that the append function is used incorrectly, but from what I can understand here I am using it in the right manner. I also do not why the function ran for 45000+ iterations before crashing.

My code is:

```
length = len(series)
counter = length // 20
remainder = length % 20

list = [''] * 20
finalList = [''] * remainder

i = 0
x = 0
y = 0

trackListCount = 0

output = []

while i < counter:

    j = 0

    while j < 20:
        list[j] = series[x]
        j += 1
        x += 1

    album1 = sp.albums(list)

    j = 0

    while j < 20:
        output.append(album1["albums"][j]["total_tracks"])
        print(album1["albums"][j]["name"])
        j += 1

    i += 1
    print(str(i) + " out of " + str(counter + 1))

if remainder != 0:
    while y < remainder:
        finalList[y] = series[x]
        x += 1
        y += 1

        album2 = sp.albums(finalList)
        y = 0

        while y < remainder:
            output.append(album2["albums"][y]["total_tracks"])
            y += 1
```

The issue occurs on the line in the second while loop:

```
output.append(album1["albums"][j]["total_tracks"])
```

As I said, for 90% of the file, the script runs fine and output remains a list, until suddenly it doesn't

Any help would be appreciated

Edit: I forgot to mention I am using the Spotipy library for my requests here: https://spotipy.readthedocs.io/en/2.18.0/

Comment: The error means that `album1["albums"][j]` is `None`.

Comment: What is `sp.albums()`?

Comment: I did, I checked that all ids were valid and return results from Spotify, as well as checking that each album had a total_tracks value that is an int.

Comment: sp.albums comes from the Spotipy library and is used to request multiple albums in 1 request, with a list as input

Comment: BTW, learn about list slices: `list = series[20*i:21*i]`

Comment: It would be helpful if you split that line into multiple assignments, so you can tell which part of the expression is causing the error. `albums = albums1["albumbs"]` `album = albums[j]` `tracks = album["total_tracks"]`

Comment: For some reason, when I have run the code again from a later point, it goes past the point where the issue was initially with no problem, could this be due to an error when receiving the data from spotify?

Comment: Or just do `print(albums1["albums"])`